# How to use factor argument with pipe operator?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner and quite excited to make my first post!

My current codes are as follow – as you see, I was using a newly created dataset which is a column-reordered version of my old dataset to make a plot.

```
nutritiondata1 <- nutritiondata
nutritiondata1$DBQ700 <- factor(nutritiondata1$DBQ700,levels = c("Poor", "Fair", "Good", "VeryGood", "Excellent")) 

nutritiondata1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(DBQ700)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=DBQ700, fill=DBQ700)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(y= "Count", x = "Diet Quality") +
  ggtitle("Diet Quality Distribution") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Diet Quality")
```

My question is: How can I format this part with the pipe operator into the rest of the codes? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Use `mutate`, such as `nutritiondata %>% mutate(DBQ700 = factor(DBQ700, levels = c("Poor", "Fair", "Good", "VeryGood", "Excellent"))) %>%` before the `filter`

Comment: Try using `mutate()` instead of the second line.